Intermediate extension of arbitrary constructible sheaves
In Achar (and other ressources), the intermediate extension functor along a locally closed embedding $h\colon Y \to X$ for varieties $X,Y$ is defined as
\begin{equation}
h_{!\ast}\colon \text{Perv}(Y)\to \text{Perv}(X)\\
\mathcal{F}\mapsto \text{im}({^pH}^0(h_{!}\mathcal{F})\to {^pH}^0(h_{\ast}\mathcal{F})).
\end{equation}
Where ${^pH}^0\colon D^b_c(X)\to \text{Perv}(X)$ is the $0-$th perverse cohomology functor, $h_{!}$ is proper pushforward and $h_{\ast}$ is regular pushforward and the map is the natural map induced by $h_{!}\to h_{\ast}$.
Now in the text it is specifically stated, that this is not well defined on all of $D^b_c(Y)$, but rather only on $\text{Perv}(Y)$, however I dont see why this is. Proper and regular pushforward both preserve constructibility (for Varieties), thus $h_{i}\mathcal{F} \in D^b_c(X)$ for all $\mathcal{F}\in D^b_c(Y)$ and moreover ${^pH}^0$ always lands in $\text{Perv}$ and as $\text{Perv}$ is abelian, the above image is well defined in $\text{Perv}(X)$ for all $\mathcal{F}\in D^b_c(Y)$.
Thanks in advance for the help.
